# Is it possible to use express in a chrome extension using browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been trying to do the aformentioned.

However, I need to trigger my bin folder that contains the www.js file when a new tab is created, which will then trigger the index.html file.

I haven't been able to do this, since chrome extensions need a default html file that will be served when a new tab is created. I tried incorporating a script tag but with no success. Is there any way to circumvent this?

In other words im trying to emulate node.js in the front-end and have heard of [node-chromify](https://github.com/iceddev/node-chromify) but no successful implementation of it.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with node.js and being an expert on chrome extensions I can't make sense of what you're trying to accomplish. Hopefully, you'll get an answer from someone who knows both environments, otherwise consider adding an example to illustrate the idea.